# Can an adapter be used for a USB-C HUB (with HDMI) to connect to a regular USB?

Tags: usb, hdmi, adapter, usb-hub

The market is full with USB Type C hubs, allowing users to connect monitors and much more to their laptops.

It is much harder to find regular USB 3 hubs with the same set of features - but my laptop has regular USB 3 connections!

Is it possible to use an adapter to connect a shiny and cool USB-C HUB (with some HDMI ports please) to my laptop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. The "regular" USB type A doesn't have alternative modes that would let it transmit video signal. Devices that provide video output over type A are actually USB video cards which can be quite heavy on the CPU. USB type C carries proper video signal from your GPU.

Comment: hmmm... Thank you! So anyting like this: https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Universal-Docking-Station-Ethernet/dp/B00ECDM78E uses a custom device driver + CPU?

Comment: + any good citation to the technology that transfers the video will be very appreciated.  This is very unclear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Video_output

Comment: As the Wikipedia link you've found says, USB type C is carrying DisplayPort signal as an alternate mode (it's using different signaling than regular DP cable). USB type A adapters use [DisplayLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink), a proprietary solution. You can actually see its logo on the photo in your Amazon link.